# How to use hangfire in .net core with mongodb?

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, nuget-package, hangfire

I want to use Hangfire for background jobs in registration form process,But I am unable to find Startup.cs file code for Hangfire.mongo.

Comment: https://dotnetthoughts.net/integrate-hangfire-with-aspnet-core/

Comment: Or if you want to use mongo to store your jobs - first hit on a search for "hangfire mongo" is https://github.com/sergeyzwezdin/Hangfire.Mongo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Startup class
In ConfigureServices method
Add

```
//you will use some way to get your connection string
var mongoConnection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MongoDBAtlasJaken");
var migrationOptions = new MongoMigrationOptions
{
    Strategy = MongoMigrationStrategy.Drop,
    BackupStrategy = MongoBackupStrategy.Collections
};

services.AddHangfire(config =>
{
    config.SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170);
    config.UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer();
    config.UseRecommendedSerializerSettings();
    config.UseMongoStorage(mongoConnection, "Hangfire",new MongoStorageOptions {   MigrationOptions = migrationOptions });

});
services.AddHangfireServer();
```

In Configure method you can add if you want

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard();
```

Answer (score 4):

Just an update to this thread,

As of v0.7.11, `MongoMigrationOptions` have been updated and no longer contains Strategy. As per the [release notes](https://github.com/sergeyzwezdin/Hangfire.Mongo#installation), you now have to use `MigrationStrategy` instead of Strategy. Also, the values you use for these are different as well. See example below.

```
var migrationOptions = new MongoMigrationOptions
{
    MigrationStrategy = new MigrateMongoMigrationStrategy(),
    BackupStrategy = new CollectionMongoBackupStrategy()
};
```

Answer (score 3):

@Graeme's anwser works on the older version of Hangfire. For the new version,

1. The `Migration` and `Backup` strategy are changed to class from enum.

   ```
    var migrationOptions = new MongoMigrationOptions
    {
        MigrationStrategy = new DropMongoMigrationStrategy(),
        BackupStrategy = new CollectionMongoBackupStrategy()
    };
   ```
2. The `UseMongoStorage` method does not accept the collection name anymore.

   ```
    services.AddHangfire(config =>
    {
        config.SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170);
        config.UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer();
        config.UseRecommendedSerializerSettings();
        config.UseMongoStorage(mongoConnection, new MongoStorageOptions { MigrationOptions = migrationOptions, CheckConnection = false });
    });
   ```

   `services.AddHangfireServer();`